# Como obter texto especifico de uma string com Regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Estou tentando manipular o retorno de uma string onde preciso obter sempre o bloco **where** do select o problema é que o meu método sempre retorna strings diferentes.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT.....
FROM.....   
WHERE
    (
        ( 
        UPPER(INDICADO.IND_DESCRI) IS NULL AND
        UPPER(CASE WHEN IND_PERIOD = 0 THEN 'LABELDIARIA'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 1 THEN 'LABELSEMANAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 2 THEN 'LABELQUINZENAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 3 THEN 'LABELMENSAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 4 THEN 'LABELBIMESTRAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 5 THEN 'LABELTRIMESTRAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 6 THEN 'LABELSEMESTRAL'  WHEN IND_PERIOD = 7 THEN 'LABELANUAL' END) = @PERIODICIDADE1 
        ) 

    )
    Order by ......
```

Precisaria obter em uma **variável** somente com o trecho where.

Comment: Não deu pra entender seu problema. Tente ser um pouco mais específico...

Comment: Sempre vai ter um `order by` depois?

Comment: Não somente ADO.NET

Comment: Sim pode por isso preciso algo dinâmico porque não sei o que pode conter depois.

Comment: Você teria que ter todos os possíveis *statements* que podem vir depois de um `where` e validar por isso...

Comment: Tu só vai ter que dar um copy da string desde o where até encontrar algo que possa parecer depois como `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, etc. ou o final da string, o que vier primeiro.

Comment: Você pode usar REGEX mas ai você vai precisar sempre ter o where em uma única linha separada. https://regex101.com/r/nA3kO7/1

Comment: Poderá existir mais de uma query no mesmo código? Ou seja  (normalmente são separados por ponto-virgula, como no exemplo) `select.....; select...`

Comment: @KhaosDoctor funcionou o seu exemplo mais quando tem quebra de linha ou "(" não pega.

Comment: Justamente, no caso desse exemplo a query do where tem que ser inline e só ter ela na linha. Se não teríamos que pegar outros exemplos para poder desenvolver uma regex mais complexa

Comment: @KhaosDoctor Então eu pensei em pegar tudo incluindo o where até o order by é possível?

Answer (score 2):

Não manjo de C#, mas fiz um código em javascript usando Regex que pode lhe trazer alguma ideia.
Se tiver mais alguma implementação, vai falando que vamos implementando esse código:

(Editei e fiz mais simples)

```js
function PegaWHERE( query ) {
  
  query = query.replace(/\n/g, '%\\n%'); // Remove quebras de linha
  
  var match = /(WHERE.*)ORDER/i.exec( query ); // Procura bloco WHERE quando ORDER existe
  
  if ( ! match ) { // Caso ORDER não exista)
  
    var match = /(WHERE.*)$/i.exec( query ); // Procura bloco WHERE sem ORDER
  
  }
  
  if ( ! match ) { // Caso WHERE não exista
    
    //return '';
    alert(''); return;
  }
  
  var where = match[1].replace(/%\\n%/g, "\n").trim(); // Devolve quebras de linhas

  //return where;
  alert( where );
}
```

```html
<textarea id="query" style="width:400px;height:100px;">select * from usuario 
where cod_usuario = 1
order by usu_nome</textarea>

<br>

<button onclick="PegaWHERE( document.getElementById('query').value )" >PEGA WHERE</button>
```

Comment: Desta forma funciona where[\s\S]*(?=order)|where[\s\S]*(?=group)|where[\s\S]*

Comment: Editei o código, fiz mais simples, porém básico. Ele encontra o bloco WHERE se existir ORDER ou não, e se por ventura o WHERE também não existir, retorna uma string vazia. Isso tudo independente se a query tiver ou não quebras de linhas.